# SOAPExtension methods not working

Tags: xml, web-services, logging, soap, trace

According to the following blog post I have done Everything. Extend the SOAP extension class and had the Config binding. Still my soap extension methods are not calling. I have put a break point and checked. Here is the Sample code. TraceExt there are more overridden methods.

[Blog](http://blog.encoresystems.net/articles/how-to-capture-soap-envelopes-when-consuming-a-web-service.aspx)

```html
 public class TraceExt : SoapExtension
    {
        Stream oldStream;
        Stream newStream;
        string filename;

        // Save the Stream representing the SOAP request or SOAP response into
        // a local memory buffer.
        public override Stream ChainStream(Stream stream)
        {
        }
    }




 <system.web>
    <webServices>
      <soapExtensionTypes>
        <add type="WindowsFormSOAP.TraceExt, WindowsFormSOAP" group="High" priority="0"/>
      </soapExtensionTypes>
    </webServices>
  </system.web>
```

Answer (score 1):

I just found an answer for this problem. When you add a web service reference you must have to add it as  the "Web Service Reference" as in .net 2.0. If you add the reference as "Add Service Reference" a new way of adding reference, the SOAP extension will not work.

### Way to do :

Right Click on Reference Folder -> Add Service Reference - > Click on Advance Button -> Add Web Reference